# issue with retrieving images from parse.com in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com and I have a problem retrieving images.  This is the code:

```
ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) comment.get("ac");
            fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() { 

                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, 
                                ParseException e) { 
                            if (e == null) { 

                                // Decode the Byte[] into 
                                // Bitmap 
                              try {
                               Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( data, 0, data.length); 

                                // Get the ImageView from 
                                // main.xml 
                               String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                File myDir = new File(root + "/imagesuri1/");    


                                String fname = "image-"+ n +".jpg";

                               n++;
                                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                               if (file.exists())
                                   {file.delete();}

                                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                       out.flush();
                                       out.close();  
                                } catch (Exception b) {
                                       b.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                // Close progress dialog 

                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            } 
                        else { 
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ha abido un problema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } 

                        }



                    });
        }
        }


    });

 no++;
```

Specifically, the problem is that I have 3 images in parse.com and I'm retrieving all the images, decoding, and saving them on an SD card. Sometimes the images return like this: 
(image-0.jpg - 0 ) (image-1.jpg - 1 ) (image-2.jpg - 2 ).  This is what I want. Sometimes the images return like this: (image-0.jpg - 0 ) (image-2.jpg - 1 ) (image-1.jpg - 2 ).  I don't understand why.

Is this a size retrieve problem of the file? Please help me with advice or solutions because I don't really understand why it gives me this result (in disorder) if I order my query correctly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code for the query but it probably is where your ordering problem is being introduced.

Try putting the following logic into the query to force the order of the images to be by the 'ac' field:

```
// Sorts the results in ascending order by the ac field
query.orderByAscending("ac");
```

See the [Query Constraints section of the Parse Android Docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-constraints) for more info.